# CentOS : Zend Framework : Can't get library path

Tags: php, centos, zend-framework

Shows PHP Fatal Error

```
main(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php'
```

I have installed ZF on `/usr/share/php`

`zf` command is working. I can create project and do other works using `zf` command.
But while including the library path then shows the error.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed `enablerepo` or forgot to update ZF.

[Please follow the steps here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-zend-framework-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/).